# What is noun to adjective conversion called?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Are there any terms used to describe the conversion of a noun into an adjective and vica versa?

```
redundant -> redundancy
```

Synonyms are when two words mean the same thing.  Is there a term similar to this for these purposes?

Comment: Related: Is there a term for when the noun and adjective have greatly different forms, such as "dog" and "canine"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process of changing a word with one grammatical function into a word with a similar meaning but a different function is called ***[Derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28linguistics%29)***.

Derivation one of the two varieties of [Morphology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_%28linguistics%29) (the other is [Inflection](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf)). English has almost no inflection left, so its morphology is almost all derivation, and quite a lot of that is [Zero Derivation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/verbing.html), where there's no suffix (*He's growing like a **weed***  vs. *I have to **weed** the garden*)

Comment: What do you think about @shoe's *adjectivization* and *nominalization*?

Comment: Those are specific types of derivation. _Verbalization_, unfortunately, already has a useful and potentially confusing meaning, so a linguist that wanted to talk about verb-forming derivation might use a still more specific form, like _causativization_. The combination of derivational markers _-ize_, _-ate_, and _-ion_ is quite productive for technical terms.

Answer (score 5):

The specific term for turning a word into an adjective is adjectivization. Nominalization (or substantivation ) is the process of turning a word into a noun.

Comment: I really wish there were a way to LINK these two answers together and give them both credit, as I have found this answer to have value as well as the first. Thank you :D